# System not exiting when i click no

Tags: java

Hello so i am making a java work and for some reason when i reached the if else one when  i click no on the dialog it doesn't exit but instead continues to ask the student name `    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student Record");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Welcome to the School's Student Grade Record!");

System.out.println("School's Student Grade Record");

int welcome = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
 JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog 
    (null, "Woild you like to input grades on the students?",
            "Grade",welcome);
 if (welcome == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
String name;
String name1 = "";
do {
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student's Name");
    if (name.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")){
        name1 = name;
        System.out.println("Student name :" +name1);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Enter Student name");
    }
    }while (!name.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]*$"));

}else {
     System.exit(0);
} 
}
```

}`

Comment: are you sure that it reach else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just copying the value of `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`(which is 0 ) into your `welcome` and later your are comparing it with `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` which is also 0 so `0==0` will always true hence `if` block will be executed always  .

The `showConfirmDialog` will give you an `int` result and you have to store it in some variable ,so use it like this

```
int welcome;

      // store the output result of showConfirmDialog in welcome

      welcome=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Woild you like to input grades on the students?",
                "Grade",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

      // compare result with predefined positive value i.e JOptionPane.YES_OPTION
     if (welcome == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
```